# angular ajax post form without binding

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, forms, post

I have form with directive for createing google catptcha (ReCaptcha).
I want to post this form via ajax to a web api hosted to another server.
There are two thing which i tried with no success.
The first one have the following code:

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="sendMail()">...</form>
```

js:

```
  ngApp.controller('ContactsController', function ContactsController($scope) {  
 $scope.recaptchamodel = "";
     $scope.sendMail = function () {

            var x = $scope.recaptchamodel;
        }
    });
```

directive:

```
    ngApp.directive('recaptcha', function () {

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            transclude: true,
            compile: function (element, attributes) {

                return {
                    pre: function (scope, element, attributes, controller, transcludeFn) {
                        Recaptcha.create("_Private_Key_", attributes.id, {
                            theme: "clean",
                            callback: function () {
                                $("#recaptcha_response_field").attr("ng-model", "recaptchamodel");

                                Recaptcha.focus_response_field;
                            }
                        });

                    },
                    post: function (scope, element, attributes, controller, transcludeFn) {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

So the thing i am trying to accomplish is to put data-ng-model attr to the recapthca html which is dynamically created. When I inspect the element after rendering the page, the attribute is on it's place. But when i submit the form "var x" is empty. It looks like the binding is not working...

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please show how the `recaptcha` is used in html.

Comment: The html in the browser is very big. This is only the input field which i am trying to bind:
<input style="border: 1px solid #3c3c3c; width: 302px;" name="recaptcha_response_field" id="recaptcha_response_field" type="text" placeholder="Type the text" autocomplete="off" ng-model="recaptchamodel">
If you need the whole HTML I can paste it here...

PS: Or you mean how i use the directive?
 <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <div recaptcha id="recaptch-container"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

Comment: I think there is very high possibility that google uses iframe because on the bottom of my rendered page there is hidden iframe but it is empty...

Comment: FOUND a solution. Actually i dont need to bind the fields from the captcha. There are two methods for retrieving the values:
Recaptcha.get_challenge(): corresponds to the "challenge" parameter required by the reCAPTCHA verification API
Recaptcha.get_response(): corresponds to the "response" parameter required by the reCAPTCHA verification API